# create dataframe of liste

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to create dataframe form existing lists( each row of file will be written in row dataframe.

```
with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='cp1252') as f: 
    lines=f.readlines()
    liste1 = str(lines[0]) 
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(liste1)
```

who can help me please?
below the 3 first rows of file f1.

```
[‘x1’, ‘major’, ’1198’,  ‘TCP’]
[‘x1’, ‘minor’, ‘1198’,  ‘UDP’]
[‘x2’, ‘major’, ’1198’, ‘UDP’]
```

Comment: Why is not used `df = pd.read_csv(filename)` ? Can you add some data sample to question ?

Comment: Maybe check this [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26333/convert-a-list-of-lists-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this properly, want each row in the DataFrame to be a string you read from a line in the file?

Note that `liste` in your case is a string so I am not sure what you are going for.

This approach should work anyways.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
with open(filename, mode='r', encoding='cp1252') as f: 
    lines=f.readlines()
    liste1 = str(lines[0]) 
    df1 = df1.append(pd.Series(liste1), ignore_index=True)
```

So if `liste1` has form

```
> "This is a string"
```

then your DataFrame will look like this

```
df1.head()

       0
0  This is a string
```

if `liste1` has form

```
> ["This", "is", "a", "list"]
```

then your DataFrame will look like this

```
df1.head()

      0   1  2     3
0  This  is  a  list
```

You can then call this `append()` routine as many times as you want inside a loop.

However, I suspect that there is a function, such as `pd.read_table()`, that can do this all for you automatically (as @jezrael suggested in the comments to your question).